# Is there a good way to merge two n-tuples?

Tags: scala, tuples, shapeless, pack

I have 2 n-tuples and I need to merge their values as parameters for a function `foo`. Currently I used a `Array` to save the merged values, which make the function call looks stupid.
I wonder if there is a good way to merge the 2 n-tuples, like saving the result into a new n-tuple (then I'll be able to call the function like `foo.tupled(mergedT)`).

```scala
def foo(p1: T, p2: T, p3: T, p4: T) = { ... }
val T1 = ... // a 8-tuple
val T2 = ... // a 8-tuple
def mergeValue[T](x: T, y: T): T = { ... }

val mv = T1.productIterator.zip(T2.productIterator).map(pair => mergeValue(pair._1, pair._2)).toArray
foo(mv(0), mv(1), mv(2), mv(3), mv(4), mv(5), mv(6), mv(7))
```

Comment: If all the types in the tuples are the same, then perhaps you need an array in the first place, and not a tuple?

Comment: Yes, all the types in the tuples are the same. Actually T1& T2 is the output of an `getParam` interface. I'm modifying the code to add a function of merging two parameter tuples.

Comment: I omitted some `asInstanceOf` in the example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with Shapeless.

Try

```
type T = String
def foo(p1: T, p2: T, p3: T, p4: T, p5: T, p6: T, p7: T, p8: T) = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7 + p8
val T1 = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
val T2 = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")

def mergeValue[T](x: T, y: T): T = ???

import shapeless.poly.->, shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

object p extends ((T, T) -> T)((mergeValue[T] _).tupled)

(foo _).tupled(T1.zip(T2).map(p))
```

Comment: Running in a worksheet, it complains about the unimplemented def: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vPm2zfwwTI2DFmwkdAs14g - how would this be implemented in a proper Main method (or other application)?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley Surely while running it complains about unimplemented def because `mergeValue` is not implemented. But the code compiles. How can I know how `mergeValue` should be implemented? This is your business logic.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley For example for `T=String` we can write `def mergeValue[T](x: T, y: T)(implicit ev: T =:= String, ev1: String =:= T): T = ev1(ev(x) + ev(y))` i.e. string concatenation. Then `(foo _).tupled(T1.zip(T2).map(p))` will be `0a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h`.